# AngularJS - Converting EPOC dates

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have a JSON file with a list of dates in EPOC format:

```
"Date": "/Date(1405967947000)/",
"Date": "/Date(1405967947000)/",
"Date": "/Date(1405967947000)/",
"Date": "/Date(1405967947000)/",
"Date": "/Date(1405967947000)/",
"Date": "/Date(1405967947000)/",
"Date": "/Date(1405967947000)/",
"Date": "/Date(1405967947000)/",
```

I know in Angular i can easily filter these into any format via:

```
convertDate = $filter('date')(myScopeToDate, 'dd MMM yyyy');
```

However, ideally i want to convert in this format:

```
Tue Oct 21 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (GMT Daylight Time)
```

So i tried:

```
var convertDate = new Date(myScopeToDate);
```

However the output is: "Invalid Date"

Comment: have you tried `new Date($filter('date')(myScopeToDate, 'yyyy-MM-dd'))`, i mean convert date to ISO format and then create Date object from it.

Comment: @HarishR - this is nearly close! Only issue is, when i follow your approach, dates are logging as GMT+0100 (GMT Standard Time) Rather than all being GMT+0000 (GMT Daylight Time)

Comment: @OamPsy did either of the answers fix your problem? I see you haven't marked either one as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use combination of the two things you put in your answer

```
       var dateString = $filter('date')(myScopeToDate, 'yyyy-MM-dd')
       var date = new Date(dateString)
```

you should try doing ToGMTString(), ToISOString(), ToLocalString() to get the string representation you want.

or the best would be to use moment.js for all date manipulation

```
       var date = moment(myScopeToDate).toDate()
```

Answer (score 2):

What you're seeing is that JavaScript's Date object doesn't understand ASP.NET's date formatting. (Side note: ASP.NET Web API does dates differently, using the [standard ISO 8601 format](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/OnTheNightmareThatIsJSONDatesPlusJSONNETAndASPNETWebAPI.aspx), thank God!)

Personally, I'd solve this using Moment.js, which has [intrinsic support for ASP.NET dates](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/asp-net-json-date/):

```
var momentDate = moment("/Date(1198908717056-0700)/");
var rawDate = momentDate.toDate(); // Tue Oct 21 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (GMT Daylight Time)
```